# Checking the Input value is Number or not in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, numeric

I have below procedure having varchar as input parameter

```
Create or Replace procedure p1(brand_code varchar2)
a varchar2(22);
Begin
SELECT  DESCRIPTION into a from UDA_VALUES
WHERE CODE =brand_code;
end;
```

In the above procedure I am facing invalid number error because the input parameter brand_code
contains the value 'ALL' but the data type of code in the UDA_VALUES table is Number data type. So how can we check the brand_code contains the numeric value?. So that I can validate and pass the brand_code in the select statement.Is there any method apart from regexp to validate the variable contains the numeric value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression is one way to solve it:

```
Create or Replace procedure p1(brand_code varchar2) AS
  a varchar2(22);
Begin
  SELECT DESCRIPTION into a from UDA_VALUES
    WHERE CODE = brand_code AND
          REGEXP_LIKE(DESCRIPTION, '[A-Za-z]+');
end p1;
```

You can get around using a regular expression with:

```
Create or Replace procedure p2(brand_code varchar2) AS
  a varchar2(22);
  n number;
Begin
  SELECT DESCRIPTION into a from UDA_VALUES
    WHERE CODE = brand_code;

  BEGIN
    n := TO_NUMBER(a);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      n := NULL;
  END;
end p2;
```

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE(DESCRIPTION, '[A-Za-z]+'); Instead of description i have to check brand_code REGEXP_LIKE(brand_code, '[A-Za-z]+')

Answer (score 0):

You can also just trap the error with an exception hander.

```
Create or Replace procedure p1(brand_code varchar2)
as
  a varchar2(22);
Begin
  begin
   SELECT  DESCRIPTION into a from UDA_VALUES
    WHERE CODE =brand_code;
  exception
    when others then
      null;
  end;

  --continue without a value for `a` if the SQL above failed
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

From 12c, TO_NUMBER supports DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR:

```
WHERE code = TO_NUMBER(brand_code DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR);
```